When I updated to expo sdk version 51, my expo app crashed when used
When I updated to expo sdk version 51, my expo app crashed when used, the console did not display an error.
When I updated to expo sdk version 51, my expo app crashed when used, the console did not display an error. ab c da dbas

You can find the answer to what you are looking for here:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/28618

This issue is related to IOS builds
was able to solve this problem by adding this to the top of your app.js
import 'react-native-reanimated'
and run this command
npm cache clean --force

this is works for me:

npm install expo@latest
npx expo install --fix
IF YOU USE  EXPO ROUTER - Comment this line in babel.config.js 'expo-router/babel'

